# How can i get value from config file and set in $attribute variable in laravel model file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to assign a default value in Laravel model but the value should come from the config file.

I am writing below code but its giving me error

```
    protected $attributes = [
        'is_generation'    => true,
        'price'       => config('test.MY_PRICE'),
    ];
```

it's showing me an error like **Constant expression contains invalid operations**

How can I get value from config file and set in $attribute variable in Laravel model file?

Comment: what do u mean by config file ? there is `.env` file in laravel where you can have global values and access them any where

Comment: env have MY_PRICE = 30
and in config file MY_PRICE = env('MY_PRICE');

Comment: You can't assign dynamic value as a default value for an attribute, or for a constant of a class. better use a method that calls the `config(...)` if no value is in your attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `saving` model *event* by adding this code to your `Eloquent Model`:

```php
protected static function boot()
{    
    // sets default values on saving
    static::saving(function ($model) {
        $model->price = $model->price ?? config('test.MY_PRICE');
    });
    parent::boot();
}
```

With this code in place, if the field `price` is `null`, it will have assigned a *value* from the *config key* just a moment *before* `saving` the `Model` in the database.

BTW you can change the check like if it's an empty string or less then a number and so on, this is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may
>   include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

The only way you can make this work is :-

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Amazon
{
  protected $serviceURL;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->serviceURL = config('api.amazon.service_url');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute mutator as explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

```
Class Example{

 public function setPriceAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['price'] = config('test.MY_PRICE');
 }
}
```

Comment: its not working for me as it only work when i try to set this attribute value while i am saving object but i dont want to do that.

Comment: It seems mutator only works with laravel eloquent like you tried using an object. Are you using query builder? Something like Model::create($data);.